# LINQ to SQL Join and If Condition

Tags: c#, linq, join, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the query below where I want to set the price if *bstock* is not null and *bstock.Price* (*bstock.Price* is a null-able doubel? ) is not null. The join is a left outer join. Can someone help me?

```
var bstocks = (from p in qry
                             join bstock in bstockRepository.Select() on p.StockCode equals bstock.StockCode
                             into J1
                             from bstock in J1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new
                             {
                                 p.StockCode,
                                 p.Description,
                                 p.ListPrice,
                                 p.Price =  bstock.Price != null ? bstock.Price : p.Price,
                                 p.QuantityOnHand ,
                                 p.Cube,
                                 p.ShippingFormat,
                                 p.Weight,
                                 p.NextShipment,
                                 p.NextShipment2,
                                 p.NextShipmentQuantity,
                                 p.NextShipment2Quantity,
                                 Bstock = p.Bstock
                             }
                              ).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0):

`bstock` can be null in your query, as you are running left join. So you need to account for that:

```
Price =  bstock != null && bstock.Price != null ? bstock.Price : p.Price,
```

Result:

```
var bstocks = (from p in qry
                join bstock in bstockRepository.Select() on 
                    p.StockCode equals bstock.StockCode into J1
                from bstock in J1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                        p.StockCode,
                        p.Description,
                        p.ListPrice,
                        Price =  bstock != null && bstock.Price != null ? bstock.Price : p.Price,
                        p.QuantityOnHand ,
                        p.Cube,
                        p.ShippingFormat,
                        p.Weight,
                        p.NextShipment,
                        p.NextShipment2,
                        p.NextShipmentQuantity,
                        p.NextShipment2Quantity,
                        Bstock = p.Bstock
                    });
```

Comment: Alex, I know it could be bull but adding that condition gives an error and won't compile. So that is what i want to do but it does not work.

Comment: Here is the error: "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

Comment: @Shuaib - Can you try to remove `Bstock = p.Bstock` in the end?

Comment: @Shuaib - ignore my last comment. It should not matter.

Comment: THANKS Alex!!! 
I got it. I had to cast to new Product. Here is the code. select new Product{}
the Bstock=p.Bstock  was a typo on my post but not part of the code.

Comment: @Shuaib - I just figured out, there was also another error in the code. Should not be `p.Price = `, but `Price = `.

Comment: @Shuaib - hope I was at least a little helpful after all.